# DecimalFormat variable group size

Tags: java, formatting

I've researched the subject somewhat before posting the question, but I couldn't find the answer.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

input: a number 7-8 decimal spaces long (no fractions).

output: "X XXXXXX X" where X is a digit, must be present.

example: 1234567 => 0 123456 7

What I tried:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols group = new DecimalFormatSymbols();  
group.setGroupingSeparator(' '); 
DecimalFormat idFormat = new DecimalFormat("0,000000,0", group);
```

But this prints something like "0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7" instead :S What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I can print what I need if I do this:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols group = new DecimalFormatSymbols();  
group.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
group.setDecimalSeparator(' ');
DecimalFormat idFormat = new DecimalFormat("0,000000.0", group);
```

And from re-reading the manual, I realized that DecimalFormat doesn't have a way to print variable length groups (I'm lucky I only need 2 - so I can use fraction part). But how would you do this "properly"? Would it be OK to use regular expression here / write my own function, or are there libraries that do this already?

**EDIT2:**

Just for kicks, below is the regex-based way of doing it :)

```
Random random = new Random();
System.out.println(
      String.valueOf(Math.round(random.nextDouble() * 1e8))
      .replaceAll("(.*)(\\d{6})(\\d)$", "$1 $2 $3")
      .replaceAll("^ ", "0 "));
```

Comment: I don't think regex would help you here - those are for parsing. AFAIK there's no way to use a regex to format a decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use the `DecimalFormat` grouping separator for this. From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

> If you supply a pattern with multiple grouping characters, the interval between the last one and the end of the integer is the one that is used. So "#,##,###,####" == "######,####" == "##,####,####".

Comment: I don't know of a common approach. I would probably just write my own, should be relatively straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ICU4J library's [com.ibm.icu.text.DecimalFormat](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/DecimalFormat.html) class for this same purpose. It supports variable length group size. For your particular case:

```
com.ibm.icu.text.DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new com.ibm.icu.text.DecimalFormatSymbols();
dfs.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
com.ibm.icu.text.DecimalFormat df = new com.ibm.icu.text.DecimalFormat("0,000000,0", dfs);
```

This should print '0 123456 7' for a number like '1234567'.