# Format double number using DecimalFormat

Tags: java, formatting

I am trying to format a double number using DecimalFormat class.

I hope this is printing based on Locale.

**Code:**

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#####,###,###.00");
String result = df.format(99999999999.99);
System.out.println(result);
```

**Actual output:**

```
99,999,999,999.99
```

**Expected Output:**

```
99999,999,999.99
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DecimalFormat variable group size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10229716/decimalformat-variable-group-size)

Comment: @azurefrog: Can we use `String.format` for this use case?

Answer (score 2):

This is not supported, and you could have read this in the javadocs.

> The grouping separator is commonly used for thousands, but in some
>   countries it separates ten-thousands. The grouping size is a constant
>   number of digits between the grouping characters, such as 3 for
>   100,000,000 or 4 for 1,0000,0000. If you supply a pattern with
>   multiple grouping characters, the interval between the last one and
>   the end of the integer is the one that is used. So "#,##,###,####" ==
>   "######,####" == "##,####,####".

Answer (score 0):

Hi Discover Shankar Bro,
Kindly refer the below link and also try to use String Interpolation And Replacement.

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-internationalization/decimalformat.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, multiple grouping is not possible using decimal format and String interpolation we cant use in Java, it is supported in Scala.